# check internet speed from terminal?

Tags: command-line, networking

How can I get the speed of my internet connection from the terminal? Is there any script or commandline application(s) available?

I'm using CentOS 6.5 .

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to that duplicate, I cover 4 excellent tools for looking at network bandwidth there.

Comment: there's a complete discussion about it : [How to check Internet Speed via Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104755/how-to-check-internet-speed-via-terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it, open your terminal and type as

```
  wget -O speedtest-cli https://raw.github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest_cli.py
     chmod +x speedtest-cli
    ./speedtest-cli
```

For example:

```
[raja@localhost ~]$     ./speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from BSNL (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by BEAM TELECOM (Hyderabad) [19.00 km]: 39.975 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 1.16 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 0.38 Mbit/s
[raja@localhost ~]$
```

Thanks to [LinOxide](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/test-internet-speed-terminal/).

Comment: both github as well as linoxide links have gone away.